# Solve Eigenvalues for Particles enclosed in a hard surface?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there a way to calculate the energy eigenvalues for a particle enclosed in an impenetrable enclosing surface? I tried evaluating the Fourier transformation of the Laplacian operator
\begin{align}
\int_V e^{-i\bar{k}\cdot \bar{x}} \nabla^2 \psi  \ dV
\end{align}
to use the surface integrals to reveal the momentum eigenvalues dependent on the surface and I was able to obtain the following result
\begin{align}
\oint_S e^{-i\bar{k}\cdot \bar{x}} \bar{\nabla} \psi \cdot d\bar{S}
=
0
\end{align}
however I do not how to specify $\bar{\nabla} \psi$ at the surface. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the box is impenetrable, perhaps it would be easier to focus on $\psi$, along with the condition that $\psi = 0$ at the surface.

Comment: The second equation assumes that $\psi = 0$ at the boundary.